# Swagger-Pre-requisites and its role in node.js

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0

I wanted to know what are the pre-requisites required to learn swagger in node.js and what is the role of swagger in node.js . Do I need to learn YAML for it? It would be helpful to know where I can find more information on swagger and its training.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger is a way to document your REST service. Its not tied to any Server side technology. Swagger can be used to document Rest services built with Java, Go or any other Tech stack.

To answer your questions.

1. pre-requisites required to learn swagger in node.js? ---- You should be
   really familiar with your contract part of your webservice. It will
   be helpful if you are a bit familiar with Json or Yaml file
2. what is the role of swagger in node.js? ---- To document the Rest services
   built with NodeJs (or any other server side technology , for that
   matter)
3. Do I need to learn YAML for it? ---- Not necessarily. You can do either
   in Json or Yaml (My personal preference is Json, because whitespace
   doesn't really mean much there)

[editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) has a nice tool with which you can validate your swagger spec, convert between json and yaml formats etc.
Take a look here http://editor.swagger.io/#/ , play a bit with swagger spec of Uber API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came to know the basic concept behind swagger.

Comment: http://swagger.io/getting-started/ This is the starting point. Get your hands dirty with http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Comment: OK.Thank you for the answer again.I accepted your answer.Have a good day.

Comment: @parth .. why do you need swagger? what is your use case?

Comment: Actually I wanted it for documentation of web APIs

Comment: @parth Web APIs is the Restful APIs (Debatable- Web APIs can be as bad as just RPCs or it can be as good as 3rd level maturity model Restful with HATEOAS)